# Como estruturar um banco mySQL a partir de um JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

Tenho a seguinte estrutura `json` de teste:

```
{
  "CE": {
    "Fortaleza": [
      {
        "nome": "Teste",
        "email": "xx@xxx.com",
        "cel": "(xx) xx-xx"
      },
      {
        "nome": "Teste",
        "email": "xx@xxx.com",
        "cel": "(xx) xx-xx"
      }
    ],
    "Abaiara": [
      {
        "nome": "Cidade Abaiara 1",
        "email": "xx@xxx.com",
        "cel": "(xx) xx-xx"
      },
      {
        "nome": "Cidade Abaiara 2",
        "email": "xx@xxx.com",
        "cel": "(xx) xx-xx"
      }
    ]
  },
  "rn": {
    "pindaiba": [
      {
        "nome": "rtyretyerty",
        "email": "xx@xxx.com",
        "cel": "(xx) xx-xx"
      },
      {
        "nome": "zzzzzz",
        "email": "xx@xxx.com",
        "cel": "(xx) xx-xx"
      }
    ],
    "sorisal": [
      {
        "nome": "sor",
        "email": "xx@xxx.com",
        "cel": "(xx) xx-xx"
      },
      {
        "nome": "sorsor",
        "email": "xx@xxx.com",
        "cel": "(xx) xx-xx"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Criei um banco de dados e estou com dúvidas de como criar minhas estruturas de tabelas a partir do `json` acima, mas não é necessário os dados.

> **`[PERGUNTA]`** A pergunta é sobre programação, pois não consigo escrever um código `SQL` que monte esse estrutura.
>
> **Objetivo**: Criar um `echo json_encode($stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));` que monte a mesma estrutura `json` acima.

### O que já tenho:

- **Conexão com o banco:**

-

```
function Conectar(){
        try{
            $opcoes = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES UTF8');
            $con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=teste;", "root", "", $opcoes);
            return $con;
        } catch (Exception $e){
            echo 'Erro: '.$e->getMessage();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

- **Busca de todos os cadastros:**

-

```
function getFilterCidade($estado){
        $pdo = Conectar();
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM locais WHERE uf = ?';
        $stm = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stm->bindValue(1, $estado);
        $stm->execute();
        sleep(1);
        echo json_encode($stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
        $pdo = null;        
    }
```

**- Nome da estrutura json para a criação das **colunas**:**

Perceba que um estado `poderá ter várias cidades` e uma cidade `poderá ter vários usuários` com: `nome , email e celular.` Nessa estrutura exemplo **temos 2 estados com 2 cidades e cada cidade com 2 usuários.**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você precisa montar um select(ou mais) que o retorno seja igual o json? se for isso poderia colocar as estruturas das tabelas?

Comment: @rray, Eu preciso saber exatamente como seria essa estrutura de tabela a partir do json que apresentei e sim, o encode deve ser tal como está no mesmo exemplo. Deveria eu acrescentar algo amais?

Comment: uma pergunta, por que retorna em json? O json será lido em php ou em javascript?

Comment: Será lido via `$.getJSON('data.php', function(data) {...`

Comment: Então é javascript.. a coisa toda se resume a "Ler um json com javascript e montar os dados numa tabela html". O PHP e MySQL ficam de fora do assunto.

Comment: Você não precisa se preocupar, na sua resposta, sobre como fazer a requisição, mas sim em como fazer essa estrutura `mySQL` e retornar o `json` em um `.php`, conforme pedido na pergunta. Ainda está confuso? Não altere a pergunta se você não entendeu.

Comment: Qu não quero "Ler dados do MySQL retornados em json com JavaScript e montar uma tabela HTML". Eu quero um código `SQL` e um `json_encode` que me gere a mesma estrutura que dei na pergunta. Não tem nada haver com javascript a resposta.

Comment: a questão é que vc nao vai criar uma estrutura mysql.. a estrutura já existe.. rsrsr .. o que eu entendi e vc havia confirmado nos comentários acima é, "o php lê os dados no mysql, retorna em json. Então vc quer montar uma tabela html com esses dados do json, com javascript".. vc mesmo confirmou isso acima.. agora não entendi nada..

Comment: agora não é "molezinha".. rsrs... estamos falando de modelagem de dados.. vc não possui a modelagem? (estrutura das tabelas). Isso não dá para fazer num post informal em 2 ou 3 minutos..  exige um certo tempo. Ao menos a modelagem das tabelas vc deve fazer, pois é seu trabalho. Eu posso meramente sugerir uma modelagem. Mas há N formas de fazer isso.

Comment: Publiquei uma resposta mais não tive tempo de testa-la ainda, por favor veja se resolve o problema, acredito  ser próximo disto.

Comment: Fiz todos os testes e está exatamente como pediu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interessante questão, porque vai na contra-mão da maior parte das perguntas, querendo gerar um json ou invés de somente ler.

Bem vamos lá:

**Tabelas:**

Criarei apenas uma tabela com as colunas `(id, Estado, Cidade, Nome, Email, Cel)`, acredito que saiba fazer, este não é o problema da questão. Pode optar por duas para evitar duplicações, mas não acredito que seja necessário *para a questão*!

**Solução:**

> Inicialmente haverá isto na tabela:

```
0, CE, Fortaleza, Teste, xx@xxx.com, (xx) xx-xx
1, CE, Fortaleza, Teste, xx@xxx.com, (xx) xx-xx
```

O que realmente deseja é agrupar baseado no CE e Fortaleza, neste caso terá que usar o while.

```
<?php

$rAux = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tabela ORDER BY Estado ASC, Cidade ASC");
// Pega todos os registros do banco de dados.

while($r = $rAux->fetch_array()){
// Criado um loop finito para cada registro

$nomeCidade = $r['Cidade'];
$nomeEstado = $r['Estado'];

$dados = array('nome' => $r['Nome'], 'email' => $r['Email'], 'cel' => $r['Cel']);
// Esta é a array que deseja que seja retornada


$jsonAux[ $nomeEstado ][ $nomeCidade ][] = $dados;
// CE -> FORTALEZA -> [Nome, Email Tel], [Nome, Email, Tel]
// O [] no final é para adicionar um novo. Assim como $array[] = 'manteiga'.


}
// Fim do loop

$json = json_encode($jsonAux);
echo $json;
```

Tentei deixar o código mais auto-explicativo possível para que possa compreender passo a passo. O PHP irá criar o caminho `CE -> FORTALEZA` na primeira vez e  depois irá adicionar a array nele,  uma vez que já existe.

## Resultado:

> MySQL:

```
--
-- Criar tabela
--
    CREATE TABLE `tabela` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Estado` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Nome` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Inkeliz',
  `Cidade` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Cel` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dados utilizados para teste
--

INSERT INTO `tabela` (`id`, `Estado`, `Nome`, `Cidade`, `Email`, `Cel`) VALUES
(1, 'CE', 'Inkeliz', 'Fortaleza', 'xxx@xxx.com', '(00)12345678'),
(2, 'CE', 'Inkeliz', 'Fortaleza', 'xxx@xxx.com', '(00)12345678'),
(3, 'CE', 'Inkeliz', 'Aquiraz', 'xxx@xxx.com', '(00)12345678'),
(4, 'RN', 'Inkeliz', 'Pindaiba', 'pinda@xxx.com', '(00)12345678');

--
-- Index
--
ALTER TABLE `tabela`ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

> JSON:

```
{"CE":{"Aquiraz":[{"nome":"Inkeliz","email":"xxx@xxx.com","cel":"(00)12345678"}],"Fortaleza":[{"nome":"Inkeliz","email":"xxx@xxx.com","cel":"(00)12345678"},{"nome":"Inkeliz","email":"xxx@xxx.com","cel":"(00)12345678"}]},"RN":{"Pindaiba":[{"nome":"Inkeliz","email":"pinda@xxx.com","cel":"(00)12345678"}]}}
```

[image: JSON]

Comment: Inkeliz, ja fez os testes?

Comment: Sim, tudo certo com era de se esperar :P

Comment: Umas das melhores perguntas e melhores respostas (visualmente e tecnicamente) do ano...

Comment: Resposta perfeita.